# How to check PHP array for key then assign value?

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an array called $myarray like this...

```
[187] => 12
[712] => 24
```

Within a loop later in my code, i want to check to see if a key exists in that array and if it does, i want to assign the corresponding value to a variable.

So I'd check like this...

```
if (array_key_exists($id), $myarray)) { 
            $newvariable= "(the value that goes with the index key)";
            } else {  
            $newvariable="";
            }
```

So if it checked for key "187", then $newvariable would be assigned "12";

I guess I just need to know what to replace "(the value that goes with the index key)" with.   Or maybe I'm approaching it wrong?

Comment: in if condition you can do like this, $myarray[$id] = value you want to assign

Comment: What is your problem? You described a scenario and answered it yourself, I don't see any issues to solve here.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear.  I just needed the " $myarray[$id]" syntax which now seems amazingly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the value of `$id` as key:

```
if (array_key_exists($id, $myarray)) { 

            $newvariable= $myarray[$id];

      } else {  

            $newvariable="";

       }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$myArr = [187 => 12, 712 => 24];

foreach($myArray as $key => $value)
{
   if($key == 187) {
      $newVariable = $value;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, this is what I was hinting at when I asked if I was approaching it wrong. Is there a benefit to doing it this way as opposed to the way I proposed?

Comment: If you want to find matches for more id's then you can easily extend functionality of my example to check if current key is existing in your list using `in_array()` of id's and then do something.